# Add custom text to Contact Form 7 via shortcode WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using Contact Fom 7 and need to add a custom text somewhere to the form.

I'm getting the custom text with PHP from a subfield of Advanced Custom Fields. I know, that there is an extra Plugin called "Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension" for that (https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/). But because the text is in a subfield, I cant use it.

So, what I need is a text in an hidden input field or in the generated e-mail of the form.

What I thought was a custom parameter in the CF7 shortcode itself. Like this:

```
[contact-form-7 id="1" title="Title" customtext="Text"]
```

Is that possible?

Or is it possible to use the title and add it to an input field or in the e-mail of the form?

Comment: is that a simple text ? then u can simply put that in output text from admin panel itself right ?

Comment: It is a simple text but it's dynamic and different on every page/form

Comment: for same form its same right ?

Comment: unfortunately not. the form is always the same and the text comes from the page (via PHP).

Comment: ohh, then need code... filter, i m quite sure filters are there. 
U look for that. I m office now. Once I get time, i will try to find solution.
If u get something early, plz post that too

Comment: one question before that.... if post title is passed, will that fulfil your requirement ?

Comment: No, I can get the post title with the "Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension". I need a custom text from the page itself. I just need the text in the form. In a hidden field or an own tag. Doesn't matter :)

Comment: What the goal of this custom custom text you want to add in your email ? If your aim is to know on witch page your visitor fill the form, you can use spcials tags in your mail (like [_url] or [_post_title]). see https://contactform7.com/special-mail-tags/

Comment: u mean some value from page meta ?

Comment: I'm using the same form on a page for multiple reasons. Let's say contact person 1, 2, 3.... And I want to add the contact person to the mail of the form. I could'n know how much contact persons are on the page

Comment: Alice: yes, a subfield from advanced custom fiields. so not directly a post_meta field

Comment: okay, I think I got a way out..... for post meta field... posting that as an answer... u can make it from subfield. And I belive this will help others too

Comment: great, would be very helpful!

Comment: @Cray I would like to know what is intension?

Comment: @VasimShaikh please see above

Comment: You want to pass email in contact form shortcode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a field named “customtext” for the destination email address:

```
[text* customtext]
```

To get the default value from shortcode attributes, add the default:shortcode_attr option to the form-tag:

```
[text* customtext default:shortcode_attr]
```

Then, add an attribute with the same name as the field (“customtext” in this case) into the shortcode for the contact form:

```
[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" customtext="xxxxxx@example.com"]
```

you need to register the attribute beforehand.

Add the following code snippet to your theme’s functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_wpcf7', 'custom_shortcode_atts_wpcf7_filter', 10, 3 );

function custom_shortcode_atts_wpcf7_filter( $out, $pairs, $atts ) {
    $my_attr = 'customtext;

if ( isset( $atts[$my_attr] ) ) {
    $out[$my_attr] = $atts[$my_attr];
}

return $out;
}
```

Referance link : https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-shortcode-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

First add the field in php

```
function cf7_add_my_field(){

    global $post;
    return $post->ID; // Here instead of returning post id, get your meta/submeta field and return that value.
}

add_shortcode('CF7_ADD_MY_FIELD', 'cf7_add_my_field');
```

Now after this add the following in your form -

```
[dynamictext my-filed-name "CF7_ADD_MY_FIELD"]
```

Note: You need "Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension" plugin, which you already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the "submeta field" is a repeater field from Advanced Custom Field. And the field I need is inside the repeater array. If I do it like in your answer, I will get X values. And I need only one of them

Comment: but from that repeater array can't we retrieve data only related to this post/post id ?

Comment: In that case i would like to suggest you to post what u r getting there from sub field. I think we will get some way out

Comment: The problem is, that one post has more than one contact person. For example: I have a post called "location" in this location, there are 10 contact persons. I get the contact persons all from the repeater field and print the name and the form for them. Inside this "while loop" I get the name, the e-mail and the form

Comment: great to hear that