# CF7 Form dynamic text value set from shortcode

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a situation where I want to make a form in which the name field is set dynamically (manually) in the shortcode. An example:

- [cf7form cf7key="dynamic-test-form" name="name=Mogosan Emanuel"]
- [cf7form cf7key="dynamic-test-form" name="name=Mogosan Claudiu"] and
  so on.

In the idea that if I have 9 cases I should not make 9 different forms.

I use the following Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension plugin, but I can't figure out how to solve my situation. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The answer from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54570902/add-custom-text-to-contact-form-7-via-shortcode-wordpress
Make it happen

Comment: Here is the direct link to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54572169/9739794

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is used to fill the fields dynamically, not manually.

For example, you can insert the username into a field using this shortcode instead of the shortcode for the name input field:

`Name: [dynamictext* your-name "CF7_get_current_user key='display_name'"]`

(found here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/possible-to-auto-fill-registered-users-name-email-and-phone/#post-14414001)

I don't know exactly what would make the most sense in your case. It would be necessary to know what problem you want to solve this way.

Comment: I posted a comment above with another topic that solves my problem highlighted here